# c - How to delete \n?

Tags: c, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to go to the previous line in a C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895541/how-to-go-to-the-previous-line-in-a-c-code)

I want to delete the last `\n` in

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     printf("****\n");
```

It seems `\b` doesn't work on this.
What should I do?

Comment: You mean you want to delete the newline after printing?

Comment: Well, better to not print it in the first place. Once it is printed, it's not so nice, as you can see in Mike's and anishsane's answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no character sequence, defined by the C standards, for cursor positioning moving the cursor up a line (or to previous text buffers). So there is no 100% portable way to do this.

However, depending on your platform, most terminal consoles support [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in which case you can do something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    printf("****\n");
printf("\033[A\033[C\033[C\033[C\033[C");
```

This uses the escape sequences for moving the curser up one line (`\033[A`) followed by moving it forward one character (`\033[C`) done 4 times to move past your 4 asterisks. Thus you'll get the effect of moving "backwards" over the newline.

In a slightly cleaner sense, you can put this in a `#define`:

```
#define BACKUP_NEWLINE "\033[A\033[C\033[C\033[C\033[C"

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("****\n");
printf("%s", BACKUP_NEWLINE);
```

A better solution (less hardcoded at least) might be using the [curses library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) or some equivalent on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

Best solution would be not to print it at all:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("****%s", ((i!=9)?"\n":""));
```

Or alternatively use two printfs(has the same effect, just in a bit more code and easier to read):

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  printf("****");
  if (i != 9 ) {
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `i = 1..10` is just an example I took. It's not that simple to determine whether it has reached the last `\n` in my work. I want to delete the printed `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("****");
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
     printf("\n****");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is bascially the same answer as Ivaylo gave, but instead of checking the condition for each iteration you could just move it out altogether:

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    printf("****\n");

printf("****");
```

Now, whether you *need* such micro-optimizations or not is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no well-defined portable way to do that, you can only change characters of the current line, as the standard says:

> **`\b`** (*backspace*) Moves the active position to the previous position on the current line. If the active position is at the initial position of a line, the behavior of the display device is unspecified.

Other answer already proved different ways to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method:

1. If you are on ansi compliant terminal, &
2. your printf DOES NOT use any white space character other than ' '(space), (e.g. \t,\n,\v etc),

you can use below code :-)

```
int t;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   t=printf("****\n");      // t would hold number of characters printed.
printf("\033M\033[%dC",t-1);
```

It uses 2 escape characters:

1. <ESC>M : Move on previous line, but first column
2. <ESC>[<num>-C : Move right by <num> locations.

If your printf happens to contain other whitespace characters, like \n,\t etc, you need to calculate using some logic, to find the horizontal cursor position.

Another method is:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   printf("****\033[s\n");      // \033[s would save column number
printf("\033M\033[u");
```

More details on ANSI escape characters [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) :-)

Comment: This seems a little hard to read~ Thanks~

Comment: I didn't understand. The "accepted answer" is just a special case of this answer, when the printf statement is constant: "****\n". This answer was a generic one, for any text in the printf. Never mind....